# Get rid of a vertical frozen pane in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I created a VBA script to customize my workbook but I accidentally created a vertical frozen pane when I was attempting to freeze rows 1-5 on each sheet.

Where in the script did I go wrong and how can I remove the frozen pane?

```vb
Sub FormatSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    ' Loop through all sheets in the workbook
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

        ' Change each column width to 9.75
        ws.Cells.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 9.75

        ' Activate the sheet before freezing panes
        ws.Activate

        ' Unfreeze all panes
        ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
 
        ' Select rows 1-5 and freeze panes
        ws.Rows("1:5").Select
        ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

        ' Set the column width of column K to 26.79
        ws.Columns("K").ColumnWidth = 26.79

        ' Set the text alignment in every column K cell to shrink to fit
        ws.Range("K:K").ShrinkToFit = True

        ' Set the row height of row 1 to 118.5
        ws.Rows(1).RowHeight = 118.5

        ' Set the margins when printing to the minimum
        ws.PageSetup.LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        ws.PageSetup.RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        ws.PageSetup.TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        ws.PageSetup.BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        ws.PageSetup.HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        ws.PageSetup.FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)

        ' Fit all columns on one page when printing
        ws.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
        ws.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = False

        ' Repeat rows 1-4 on each page
        ws.PageSetup.PrintTitleRows = "$1:$4"
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try.

```vb
    With ActiveWindow
        ' Unfreeze all panes
        .FreezePanes = False
        ' freeze 1-5 rows
        .SplitColumn = 0
        .SplitRow = 5
        .FreezePanes = True
    End With
```